# what is this url mean in django 

Tags: python, regex, django, url

this is my code :

```
(r'^q/(?P<terminal_id>[^/]+)/(?P<cmd_type>[^/]+)/?$', 'send_query_cmd'),
```

the view is :

```
def send_query_cmd(request, terminal_id, cmd_type):
```

waht about `?p` mean .

i dont know what is this url mean  ,

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?P<id>REGEXP)` is the syntax for python regular expression named group capturing.
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html ->> scroll down to `(?P...`

As for what the P stands for.. parameter? python? Origin sounds fun.

Anyways, these same regular expressions are what the django URL resolver uses to match a URL to a view, along with capturing named groups as arguments to your view function. 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters

The simplest example is this:

```
(r'^view/(?P<post_number>\d+)/$', 'foofunc'),

# we're capturing a very simple regular expression \d+ (any digits) as post_number 
# to be passed on to foofunc

def foofunc(request, post_number):
    print post_number

# visiting /view/3 would print 3.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is nothing to do with Django, but just Python's standard regular expression handling via the `re` module.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from Python [regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). The (?P...) syntax is a named group. This means that the matched text is available using the given name, or using Django as a named parameter in your view function. If you just use brackets with the ?P then it's an unnamed group and is available using an integer which is the order in which the group was captured.

Your URL regex means the following...

```
^ - match the start of the string
q/ - match a q followed by a slash
(?P<terminal_id>[^/]+) - match at least one character that isn't a slash, give it the name terminal_id
/ - match a slash
(?P<cmd_type>[^/]+) - match at least one character that isn't a slash, give it the name cmd_type
/? - optionality match a slash
$ - match the end of the string
```